# Float in JPQL query

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, jpql

I have a following method:

```
public Book findBookByTitleAndVersion(String title, Float version) {
    TypedQuery<Book>query = em.createQuery("SELECT b FROM Book b WHERE b.title = ?1 AND b.version = ?2" ,Book.class);

    query.setParameter(1, title);
    query.setParameter(2, version);
    return query.getSingleResult();
}
```

I'm using MySQL and I have some records that should be returned. I store 'version' as float type (1.22 in my case). This query returns:

`javax.persistence.NoResultException: No entity found for query`

Float has something to do here, as query by title works fine.

Comment: It's pretty unsafe to use floating point values for exact comparison. Version *really* shouldn't be a float in the database, so this is mainly a design problem.

Comment: so what would you suggest as an alternative?

Comment: More than likely. Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples and change version to a string.

Comment: A string, an int, there are plenty of choices. There's no reason it needs to be a floating point value, and there's no advantages (but plenty of disadvantages) in it.